# Pasar valores de una clase a otra

Tags: poo, clase, flutter, dart

Estoy trabajando con Dart y Flutter para crea una app móvil, la cual esta recogiendo los datos de una base de datos MySQL lo cual hace perfectamente, el problema que tengo es que no consigo hacer que lo datos que tengo en la primera clase de la base de datos se pasen a una clase distinta.

Tengo pensado hacer un inicio de sesión para el usuario y una vez dentro el usuario pueda ver sus datos modificarlos y demás, pero no quiero que el usuario tenga que estar introduciendo su usuario y contraseña constantemente para hacer esas consultas en la base de datos. Por lo que recojo los valores esos al entrar y ya los almaceno para más adelante.

Por ahora he probado creando una clase llamada Clientes, que me recoge los datos de Numero de Tarjeta (seria como el nombre de usuario), y la clave de la tarjeta (seria como la contraseña).

Clase Cliente:

```
class Cliente {
    String NumeroTarjeta;
    String ClaveTarjeta;

    String getNumeroTrjeta() {
        return NumeroTarjeta;
    }
    String getClaveTarjeta() {
        return ClaveTarjeta;
    }

    void setNumeroTarjeta(String NumeroTarjeta) {
        this.NumeroTarjeta = NumeroTarjeta;
    }
    void setClaveTarjeta(String ClaveTarjeta) {
        this.ClaveTarjeta = ClaveTarjeta;
    }
}
```

Clase 1 (Donde obtengo los valores, la clase Cliente ya esta instanciada como cliente):

```
onPressed: () async {
    var conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
        if (conn != null){
            print("Conectado a la base de datos");
        }
        else {
            print("Fallo al conectar a la base de datos");
        }
        var NumeroTarjeta = ControllerTarjeta.text;

        var results = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta = ?', [NumeroTarjeta]);
        if (results != null){
            print("Leectura de la base de datos correcta");
            print(results);
        }
        else{
            print("Ha ocurrido un error al leer en la base de datos");
        }

        for (var row in results) {
            if(row[26].toString().trim() == ControllerTarjeta.text && row[27].toString().trim() == ControllerClave.text){
            print("Coinciden los caracteres");
            cliente.setNumeroTarjeta("${row[26]}");
            print(cliente.getNumeroTrjeta());

            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => menunikkiclub()));
        }
        else{
            print("No se encontraron coincidencias en la base de datos");
        }
    };
```

Clase 2 (Donde quiero recoger esos datos)

```
child: new MaterialButton(child: Image.asset("lib/img/EstrellaConsultarPuntos.png",width: 300),
    onPressed: (){
        print(cliente.getNumeroTrjeta().toString());//Me devuelve null
        /*Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => contacto()));*/
    })
```

Comment: Es necesario que detalles mas tus clases para poder darte una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: JDev que mas necesitarias? es que el código es extenso para ponerlo todo

Comment: @Jdev aqui tienes un enlace con los archivos https://github.com/Acoidan/jugueteriasnikki

Comment: Basicamente cual es el objetivo de la Clase1 y la Clase2 para ver como interconectar los datos.

Comment: Elimino mi respuesta dado que efectivamente, estaba equivocado.

Comment: El objetivo de la clase 1 es un login sencillo el usuario introduce sus datos, y los compruebo en la base de datos a ver si existen y si existen avanzo a la sigiente ventana, que es donde quiero tener los datos del usuario para poder realizar mas funciones como mostrar sus datos para que los modifique etc @JDev

Comment: ANOTACION IMPORTANTE la clase 1 seria NikkiClub, y la clase 2 MenuNikkiClub

Comment: Si solo vas a tener un cliente puedes utilizar el patron Singleton. No se si es la mejor opción pero te soluciona el problema -> https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton

Comment: Como si solo voy a tener un cliente? Te refieres a un solo usuario? la aplicacion es para ser usada por mas de 80.000 usuarios pero logicamente cada uno con su app.@JDev

Comment: Si, ¿pero la app solo va a ser usada por un cliente por telefono a la vez no?

Comment: @JDev si si eso si, lo que no he visto la forma de como implementar un singleton para lo que necesito, si me pudieras ayudar lo agradeceria por que no veo en internet como funciona en si el singleton en Dart he visto cosas así pero no veo que haga lo que necesito. https://medium.com/@m_knabe/singletons-in-flutter-dart-f3fc94d9d9f7 

Muchas gracias desde ya por la ayuda

Comment: @AcoidanNegrínSocorro por desgracia no conozco Dart lo suficiente para poder ayudarte.